# How can change the background color of a circle in the page with a circle and the onclick() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have to create a circle with a different background color using canvas in html, and on the bottom of it, i wanna make a button that changes the background color of the circle on clicking it and then changes the color back on clicking it again. How do i do that?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid black;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    drawCircle(ctx,false);
    function drawCircle(context,fill){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(90, 90, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
        context.fillStyle="green";
    }
    $("#c1").click(function(){ drawCircle(ctx,true); });

}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1 offset3">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <br/><a id="c1" href="#" style="margin-left:70px;">click</a>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: I dont really know how to do it so i didn't really do it. I know how to make circles on canvas and how to add colors and stuff to them but making a circle that can change its background color in canvas on click is quite hard. Its easier with div but not with canvas :/

Comment: It looks like you don't understand the concept of this website. You don't get free tutorials on demand here. It is used only for solving specific problems and you need to provide the proof that you worked on the problem yourself. At least provide the code of what you have so far.

Comment: yea i am sorry. i have added the codes i used. I am able to change the background color now but not change it back to its former color

Answer (score -1):

You can not magically change the (background) color of any component drawn to the canvas.

You need to draw a new circle with a different color and override the previous circle.